# Deselect selected text in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I have an editor in which I want to check that selected text will not contain some words.  If it contains those particular words, then I need to deselect the selection made by user.  Is there any way to do that in `JTextPane`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text selection is temporaray and contiguous. You can't unselect some text in the middle of a larger string of selected text.

Maybe you are talking about highlighting. Check out the API for getHighlighter(). You can add/remove highlights and specify the start/end offsets of each highlight.

Comment: or just jtextpane.setSelectionStart(0); and jtextpane.setSelectionEnd(0); and it will "clear" the selection.

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure, but try this method.

```
textPane.setCaretPosition(start);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
int end = pane.getSelectionEnd();
pane.setSelectionStart(end);
pane.setSelectionEnd(end);
```

This will deselect the selected text and leave the caret at the end of whatever the user selected.  It might pay to pop a `JOptionPane` telling the user why the selection disappeared..

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
    null, 
    "Don't select swear words!", 
    "Net Nanny says..", 
    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```