# Java Swing Spell Checker

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, spell-checking

I have a quick question about implementing my SpellChecker into my Swing Text Editor. I tried to search around but couldn't find anything on how to get the red squiggly line under misspelled words. Is there something I could import then call on those misspellings? Also, how would I be able to make a menu pop up when I right-click on those miss spelled words? Thanks

Comment: You would have to draw the red wiggly lines.  There are word lists you can use to check word spelling,  A JDialog could show the possible words.  http://www.gwicks.net/dictionaries.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is plenty of material out there depending on what you want to do...

First of, use a `JTextPane`, which supports nice text formatting options.

### How to underline text:

Comments are included as explanations.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.Style;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyleContext;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;

public class WordUnderline {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            final Style defaultStyle = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext().getStyle(StyleContext.DEFAULT_STYLE);
            
            final JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
            
            //My super-creative text...
            pane.setText("These are words...\nHere come more words!\nWord word word.");
            
            final StyledDocument doc = pane.getStyledDocument();
            doc.addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
                private void clearStyle(final DocumentEvent e) {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> doc.setCharacterAttributes(0, doc.getLength(), defaultStyle, true));
                }
                
                @Override
                public void insertUpdate(final DocumentEvent e) {
                    //When you type a new letter, we want to (lets say) clear all the styles from the whole document...
                    clearStyle(e);
                }

                @Override
                public void removeUpdate(final DocumentEvent e) {
                    //When you erase a letter, we want to (lets say) clear all styles from the whole document...
                    clearStyle(e);
                }

                @Override
                public void changedUpdate(final DocumentEvent e) {
                    //When changing the style of the document, we want to do nothing else (but the change will happen).
                }
            });
            
            final JButton doit = new JButton("Underline selected text!");
            doit.addActionListener(e -> {
                final SimpleAttributeSet sas = new SimpleAttributeSet();
                StyleConstants.setUnderline(sas, true);
                /*I would suggest here to experiment a bit with the StyleConstants
                class... For example: StyleConstants.setBackground(sas, Color.RED);*/
                final int start = pane.getSelectionStart();
                final int end = pane.getSelectionEnd();
                doc.setCharacterAttributes(start, end - start, sas, true);
            });
            
            final JPanel contents = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            contents.add(doit, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
            contents.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            
            final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Word underline.");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().add(contents);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

---

### How to pop a menu on word selection:

Comments are included as explanations.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.Popup;
import javax.swing.PopupFactory;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;
import javax.swing.text.Utilities;

public class WordPopUp {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            final JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
            
            //My super-creative text...
            pane.setText("These are words...\nHere come more words!\nWord word word.");
            
            pane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                private boolean pendingPopUp = false; //Indicates whether we have already a popup popped up...
                
                private void pop(final MouseEvent mevt) {
                    if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(mevt)) {
                        try {
                            final StyledDocument doc = pane.getStyledDocument();

                            //Get the location of the document where the user clicked:
                            final int offset = pane.viewToModel(mevt.getPoint());
                            
                            //Find what word is at the location of the document where the user clicked:
                            final int start = Utilities.getWordStart(pane, offset),
                                      end = Utilities.getWordEnd(pane, offset);
                            
                            //Set the selection to be that word:
                            pane.setSelectionStart(start);
                            pane.setSelectionEnd(end);
                            
                            //Obtain the value of the selected word:
                            final String word = doc.getText(start, end - start);

                            //Create the contents of the popup:
                            final JPanel popupPanel = new JPanel();

                            //Create the alternative words (via JButtons):
                            final int cnt = 4;
                            final ArrayList<JButton> words = new ArrayList<>();
                            for (int i = 0; i < cnt; ++i) {
                                final JButton button = new JButton(word + (i + 1));
                                popupPanel.add(button);
                                words.add(button);
                            }
                            final JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
                            popupPanel.add(cancel);

                            //Create the popup itself:
                            final Popup popup = PopupFactory.getSharedInstance().getPopup(pane, popupPanel, mevt.getXOnScreen(), mevt.getYOnScreen());

                            //Hook action listenere to the word and cancel buttons:
                            words.forEach(button -> button.addActionListener(e -> {
                                try {
                                    //Get the text of that button (it is going to be the new word):
                                    final String newWord = ((JButton) e.getSource()).getText();
                                    
                                    //Replace the old text with the new one:
                                    doc.remove(start, end - start);
                                    doc.insertString(start, newWord, null);
                                    
                                    //Prepare caret position, so the user can keep on writing:
                                    pane.setCaretPosition(start + newWord.length());
                                }
                                catch (final BadLocationException | RuntimeException x) {
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(pane, "Oups!");
                                }
                                finally {
                                    popup.hide();
                                    pendingPopUp = false;
                                }
                            }));

                            //On cancel, deselect the selected text and close the popup:
                            cancel.addActionListener(e -> {
                                popup.hide();
                                pane.setSelectionStart(offset);
                                pane.setSelectionEnd(offset);
                                pendingPopUp = false;
                            });
                            
                            pendingPopUp = true;
                            popup.show();
                        }
                        catch (final BadLocationException | RuntimeException x) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(pane, "Oups! No word found?...");
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                private void maybePop(final MouseEvent mevt) {
                    if (mevt.isPopupTrigger()) {
                        if (pendingPopUp)
                            System.err.println("A popup is already popped. Close it to pop a new one.");
                        else
                            pop(mevt);
                    }
                }
                
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(final MouseEvent mevt) {
                    maybePop(mevt);
                }
                
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(final MouseEvent mevt) {
                    maybePop(mevt);
                }
                
                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(final MouseEvent mevt) {
                    maybePop(mevt);
                }
            });
            
            final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Word underline.");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(pane));
            
            //Give some room to spare:
            final Dimension dim = frame.getPreferredSize();
            dim.width += 100;
            dim.height += 100;
            frame.setPreferredSize(dim);
            
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

---

### Resources and references:

1. [How to Use Editor Panes and Text Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html)
2. [clickable text from jTextPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30898039/clickable-text-from-jtextpane)
3. [making text underline font by using JTextPane?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414126/making-text-underline-font-by-using-jtextpane)
4. [How to get selection from JTextPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492817/how-to-get-selection-from-jtextpane)
5. [How to clear all styling from StyledDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186160/how-to-clear-all-styling-from-styleddocument)
6. [Getting 'Attempt to mutate notification' exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15206586/getting-attempt-to-mutate-notification-exception)
7. [How do I set different colors for text and underline in JTextPane?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072171/how-do-i-set-different-colors-for-text-and-underline-in-jtextpane)
8. [Underline StyleConstant in a different colour with AttributeSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502654/underline-styleconstant-in-a-different-colour-with-attributeset)
9. [Deselect selected text in JTextPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744028/deselect-selected-text-in-jtextpane)

Answer (score 1):

> how to get the red squiggly line under misspelled words.

You can highlight the text and use a custom Painter to draw the red squiggly line.

Check out the [Squiggle Painter](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/28/rectangle-painter/) for the custom painting code.

Basic usage would be:

```
SquigglePainter red = new SquigglePainter( Color.RED );

try
{
    textField.getHighlighter().addHighlight( ?, ?, red );
}
catch(BadLocationException ble) {}
```

where the "?" would be the start/end offset of the text you want to underline.